# How to extend forms max title size

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to extend VB.Net's form title (MyForm.Text) beyond 54 chars 
    for some reason at the moment it stops at 54

thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because the form isn't wide enough?

Compare (title is 100 characters, but form width does not allow to show them all):

[image]

vs (same title, but the form is now wide enough):

[image]